# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Height (mm)'

Tags: python

```
import csv
from decimal import *

def mean(data_set):
    return Decimal(sum(data_set)) / len(data_set)

def variance(data_set):
    mean_res = mean(data_set)
    differences = []
    squared_res = []
    for elem in data_set:
        differences.append(elem - mean_res)
    for elem in differences:
        squared_res.append(elem ** 2)
    return mean(squared_res)

def standard_deviation(data_set):
    variance_res = variance(data_set)
    return variance_res ** Decimal('0.5')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("dog_data.csv", "r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        height_data = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            height_data.append(int(row[1]))
        print "Mean: {}".format(mean(height_data))
        print "Variance: {}".format(variance(height_data))
        print "Standard Deviation:{}".format(standard_deviation(height_data))
```

Here I'm getting an ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Height (mm)'.. What does this mean? How do i tackle this error ?

Comment: It means that that cell contains the string `'Height (mm)'` rather than a string representing a number. Double-check your CSV file. It looks like there's a header row that you need to skip.

Comment: You will get this exact error if you do `int("Height (mm)")` The first thing you should do before asking a question is to verify your assumptions about the values used in the loop. A simple `print(row)` would shed a lot of light on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you read the header (first line) which contain words, and you try to parse it as int.

Try to add

```
next(csv_reader, None)
```

Before your loop to skip first row.

As to "How do I tackle that error", for next time simply use print:

```
print row[1]
```

Right before the line that produced the error. See what you actually try to convert to int..

Answer (score 0):

use `height_data[:-11]` or `height_data[:-12]` (if you have a `space` between you number and `Height (mm)`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("dog_data.csv", "r") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        height_data = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            height_data.append(int(row[1]))[:-12] # depends on you want to through away how many characters 
        print "Mean: {}".format(mean(height_data))
        print "Variance: {}".format(variance(height_data))
        print "Standard Deviation:{}".format(standard_deviation(height_data))
```

---

**Updates:**

Assume this is what in you csv data

```
Dog Height(mm)
Sammi 600 
Doyle 470
Margo 170
Cookie 430
Dandriff 300
```

Save both of us some trouble and life is too short, use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df

Out[49]: 
        Dog  Height(mm)
0     Sammi         600
1     Doyle         470
2     Margo         170
3    Cookie         430
4  Dandriff         300

df['Height(mm)'].mean()
Out[50]: 394.0

df['Height(mm)'].std()
Out[51]: 164.7118696390761
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. it throws an error as follows
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Intro to python\Week_5_Videos\question_3.py", line 27, in <module>
    print "Mean: {}".format(mean(height_data))
  File "D:\Intro to python\Week_5_Videos\question_3.py", line 5, in mean
    return Decimal(sum(data_set)) / len(data_set)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 1321, in __truediv__
    return context._raise_error(DivisionUndefined, '0 / 0')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py", line 3873, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: 0 / 0

Comment: @SiddharthaNReddyMorramreddy, show me a piece of your raw data and the error message

Comment: Dog,Height (mm)
Sammi,600
Doyle,470
Margo,170
Cookie,430
Dandriff,300

error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Height (mm)'

Comment: @SiddharthaNReddyMorramreddy, You need to EDIT in your Question, show the header lines and 3 data rows in proper format.

Comment: [Dog,Height (mm)]

[Sammi,600]
[Doyle,470]
[Margo,170]
[Cookie,430]
[Dandriff,300]
**
error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Height (mm)' **