# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get the following error on python 2.7 . 'Hello' is last word in a line from the text file.The following solutions did not work for me [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Height (mm)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319409/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-height-mm)

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello.'
```

when executing the following code

```
import io

with io.open(r'C:\Python\Data\somefile.txt','r+') as f:
    bytecolumn = (line.rsplit(None,1)[1] for line in f)
    bytes = (int(x) for x in bytecolumn if x != '-')
    print('Total', sum(bytes))
```

I also tried using

```
int(float(x))
```

but it throws the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: hello.
```

P.S - I have looked at all similar questions here in stack overflow , none of the solutions worked. That is the reason to post. Please don't mark duplicate

**Edit** : I am trying to find the size of the word . that is the reason I am doing a sum and calling generators

Comment: The error is **pretty explicit**, you are at some point taking the text `hello` and trying to convert it to an integer.  Unsurprisingly, trying to convert `hello` to a float would fail too.  **Use a debugger**, print the offending line, that should help you figure out what's wrong

Comment: *Why* are to trying to convert Hello to an integer? What result are you hoping to get?

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you are trying to do. You seem to understand that the last string is `"hello"`, so I'm not sure exactly what it is you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I have updated the post . I am trying to sum the size of last word of each line from the file object( f)

Comment: @Joe_12345 uh, by size do you mean `len(word)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant size in bytes

Comment: @Joe_12345 what exactly do you mean? You're going to need to be specific. The size, in bytes, of *what exactly*? It is usually clearest if you give example input and example output.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , I am sorry for not providing an example of output. I would like to know the byte size of string. example what will be the byte size of string 'hello' . I know int(x) is not right way. Example byte size for word 'hello' should be 4 . I would like to know how to get it

Comment: @Joe_12345 pretty sure you just want `len(word)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked. Instead of using `int(x)` , we need to use

```
len(x.encode('utf-8'))
```

so the final code is updated as

```
import io

with io.open(r'C:\Python\Data\somefile.txt','r+') as fp:
    bytecolumn = (line.rsplit(None,1)[1] for line in fp)
    bytes = ( len(x.encode('utf-8'))  for x in bytecolumn if x != '-')
    print('Total', sum(bytes))
```